# Проблема с местом на жёстком диске на windows11

Tags: windows, ssd, storage, windows-11

Купил я ноут с ssd на 500гб, сразу была установлена 11 винда. Вобщем я сразу как купил не обратил внимание, начал скачивать програмки как всегда, браузер и всё остальное. Потом глянул, а у меня диск C только 146гб вместо 500гб. Кучу всего перепробовал, и никак не могу достать то остальное место. Вот странный скрин менеджера дисков, снизу показует что места 500гб, но раздел ёмкостью 150гб.

[image: Скрин менеджера дисков]

Comment: 1) Вы бы для полноты вопроса написали на русском, что там за текст на украинском скрытый внизу (про шифрование, файлы и т.д.). 2) Кстати, было у меня что-то подобное, оказался SSD не то неисправен, не то разбит криво - сдавал на гарантийный ремонт. Но у вас не обязательно то же самое, конечно.

Comment: Снизу написано: зашифровано с помощью BitLocker (это я пробовал отключить, не помогло)
Исправен, Закачка, Файл подкачки, Аварийный дамп, основной раздел. 
Как думаете, если криво разбит диск, то переустановка винды может помочь?

Comment: Ты не первый, кто с этим сталкивался https://www.diskpart.com/articles/500gb-hard-drive-shows-only-130-gb-of-space-5740i.html В статье называют такие причины (1) Не всё место выделено под С (самый простой случай, надо выделить оставшееся) (2) Ëмкость урезана производителем ноутбука намеренно (3) Неправильно отформатирован (надо переформатировать) (4) Раздел был создан клонированием меньшего диска (выделить оставшееся или переформатировать) (5) Вирус (переформатировать?)

Comment: Хуже от переустановки Винды не станет, полагаю, но вероятность, что поможет - 5-10% максимум.

Comment: Я подозреваю, что у тебя не всё место выделено. В первом списке указаны Раздел 1 и Раздел 4.  Я так понимаю, винда на Разделе 2. А в Разделе 3 как раз всё оставшееся место, не выделенное ни под какой диск.

Comment: @AlexanderPavlov и что с этим делать? ведь расширение тома недоступно, потому что как бы формально  всё место и так занято. Да и не понятно почему снизу эти скрытые разделы не отображаются, а должны.

Comment: По правому клику на разделе `467.69 ГБ` какое меню показывает?

Comment: @AlexanderPavlov Выпадает меню с активными пунктами: Открыть, Просмотреть, Сменить букву, Зжать том, Свойства, Справка. Форматирование и расширение тома недоступно...

Comment: ну не знаю тогда